# Como fazer uma aplicação híbrida para Android rodar em background?

Tags: android, ionic

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma aplicação híbrida para Android ter um serviço rodando em background onde mesmo com a aplicação fechada eu consiga receber informações de um servidor e notificar o usuário. Essa aplicação é desenvolvida em JavaScript utilizando o framework *IONIC*.

Answer (score 1):

Então, imagino que voce esta utilizando phonegap/cordova, para criar o aplicativo vc vai precisar fazer seu app rodar em background e utilizar a Push Notifications, que é configurado no aplicativo e no google dashboard.

[Push Notifications](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

[google dashboard](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

E para manter seu app em background, coloque no arquivo config.xml

```
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
```

Comment: No caso no xml de configuração do android o android manifest

Comment: Se vc estiver usando apenas phonegap build é config.XML se não é o manifest. XML sim